# Java implementation of slidemenu library for Android

Tags: java, android, slide

Im using [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library for a slidemenu in Android. This is working fine but I'm wondering if somebody has an implementation for the menu. Im trying to switch activities or fragments when a listitem is clicked but its not working. I have declared a new xml layout which is set as menu layout with the code:

```
menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);
```

The layout shows up nice but i have no idea how to manipulate the mainactivity to show a new fragment or activity.

Does somebody have a good implementation of this library?

My Slidemenu implementation:

```
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.setShadowWidth(20);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffset(150);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);


        menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);
        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.secondary_menu);

        menu.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);

menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menu.toggle();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented this with succes. It was kind of complex but I'm willing to lend a hand. Feel free to comment on this question so I can provide you some help.